# How does the representer theorem relate to the kernel trick?

Tags: kernel-trick

When I first studied the representer theorem and the kernel trick from my professor's notes, I thought that the representer theorem implied that we could write any problem in kernelized form (and by that I mean that the data enters the objective function as a kernel matrix $XX^T$), and therefore we could use the kernel trick for any problem to compute the kernel matrix. The notes aren't really clear in that part though, so I'm not sure at all about that. Looking online I think I understood that the representer theorem comes in handy when predicting a new point (correct me if I'm wrong), since:

$\hat{y} = \Phi(\hat{x})^T w^* = \Phi(\hat{x})^T\Phi(X)^T\alpha^* = \sum_{i=1}^n K(\hat{x}, x_i)\alpha_i^*$

where X is the design matrix, K is the kernel function, w is the vector of weights and alpha the coefficients coming from the representer theorem.

But still I'm not sure about the first point: does the representer theorem also imply that we can write any problem in a kernelized form?

Comment: no: the representer thm does not tell us that "any problem" can can be kernalized; I think what you're looking for is the idea of the "kernel trick": which does not say that *any* problem can be kernalized (because this isn't true), but rather that whenever you see a finite dimensional inner product, as in the entries of the matrix $\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{X}$, you can replace it with a different inner product defined by a kernel if you like. A representor thm associated with a given kernel prolbem instead tells us that the solution to that problem lives in a finite dimensional space.